# Getting a service started automatically when another gets started

Tags: systemd

I have a service that depends on another:

```
[Unit]
After=main.service
Requires=main.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/dependent
Restart=always
```

The kool things:

- Running `systemctl stop main` causes this `dependent` service to also stop
- Running `systemctl restart main` causes `dependent` service to also get started

But, running `systemctl main start` does not cause this dependent service to get started.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `After=` and `Before=` parameters are **strictly** for ordering the startup (and maybe the shutdown) of two services if both are asked to be started. Having a service listed there doesn't mean that those services will also be started up.

If you want to control whether or not another service gets started, you need to use `Requires=`, `Wants=`, or `Conflicts=` (which go in the `[Unit]` section) or `WantedBy=` (which goes into the `[Install]` section).

In your case, you want to start a service when something it's dependent on is started (which doesn't happen automatically, as there is no reason to do so). You'll want to add the following to the file and then run `systemctl enable dependent`:

```
[Install]
WantedBy=main.service
```

This says that when `main` is started, to also start this service, and that if this service happens to fail, then don't stop `main`.

Comment: It's worth noting that by itself, adding the `WantedBy=` as suggested won't get the other service to start with `systemctl start main.service`. It's not until the main.service is enabled that happens. See the associated docs for `WantedBy=` here...

Comment: Sorry, forgot the link: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/systemd.unit.5.html  Also note that *still* doesn't seem to work for my test despite creating a symlink. Using "Wants=" instead in the Unit section works the best but requires a potentially unwanted reference from main.service back to the dependent service.

Comment: Thank you for this ! It works fine.