# How to ensure custom Debian service starts first?

Tags: boot, daemon, beagleboneblack

I am writing a custom application on Debian on a beaglebone black variant. I want to have my application be the first service that gets started when the system boots, and I want the system to wait until my application gives the all clear (is finished initializing) before it starts any other services within reason. I would want it to start after the file system but before networking for example.

What strategy can I use to achieve this?

Comment: [Would this be a relevant answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21832006/10256002) or are you looking for something more [like this?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/219989/276845)

Comment: In addition to @kemotep 's comment, you should [review this](https://fedoramagazine.org/systemd-unit-dependencies-and-order/). So in general, your "strategy" should be to use `systemd`, and learn how it works :)

Comment: Yes, so this is would be a conglomerate of all three links. Systemd it is.